# How to make a selector button in style of theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I want to make style of theme as if it was a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/color_blue_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/color_blue_focused"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@color/color_blue"/> <!-- default -->
```

I think that it is form. But I don't know as to put color_blue_pressed

```
 <style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

I hope somebody of you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_workout_selected_btns" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_workout_selected_btns" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_workout_selected_btns" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_workout_normal_btns"/>
```

for color you can use

```
<item android:state_pressed="false"><shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/hoverblue" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    </shape></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_cancel_btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_cancel_btn_over" android:state_focused="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_cancel_btn_normal"></item>
```

For Creating Shape Drawables use:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#FFFF0000"
    android:startColor="FFFFFF00" />

</shape>
```